# What unit of measurement google chrome heap snapshot retained size being measured as?

Tags: google-chrome

What unit of measurement google chrome heap snapshot retained size being measured as?

It just gives a number, with no indicator if it is bytes, kilobyte, or something else.  I can't find anything on Google's docs either.

Comment: "bytes" according to the reply on Twitter: https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/707400920686993408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the reply from @jiyinyiyong it is `bytes`